# Getting time difference in python 2.7

Tags: python, datetime

I am importing some data from a REST API into a list. One of the columns contains just date/time information.

Column A format/example : `2015-06-11 07:59:10.000 GMT`

I need to be able to check the time difference between two rows , i tried using

```
datetime.strptime(variable_name, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

however i got the following error :

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .000 GMT
```

Is there any way to fix this without having to modify and remove the offending part out of every entry in my list ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
datetime.strptime (time , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")
```

"**%f**" is for anything that comes after the seconds. It will give the microseconds and "**%Z**" will give the the time zone

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `%f` for decimal part and `%Z` for timezone :

```
>>> variable_name='2015-06-11 07:59:10.000 GMT'
>>> datetime.strptime(variable_name, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 11, 7, 59, 10)
```